# Should I use ‘gotten’ or ‘got’ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I think ‘got’ sounds better, but I’d rather my sentence be correct than pretty.

My sentence: The things she’d told him couldn’t be got out of her by just anyone.

Is ‘got’ correct or should I use ‘gotten’?

Comment: "Gotten" sounds much more natural to me in that sentence.

Comment: "Gotten" sounds unnatural in British English.

Comment: You need a tag to specify whether you are asking about American or British English. _Gotten_ is regarded as archaic in British English.

Comment: Gotten is not British English so I have tagged it American English. @KateBunting says it is regarded as archaic — I would say it is obsolete as British English. I was not aware that Shakespeare ever used it, although [this site](https://stroppyeditor.wordpress.com/2017/03/27/the-us-has-gotten-this-word-back-and-the-uk-probably-will-too/) puts me right on that. It also quotes the Coverdale Bible, but I am not aware that it is in the KJV Bible.

Comment: @WeatherVane In RP English maybe, but since I moved to Merseyside, I’ve gotten used to hearing ‘gotten’.

Comment: @David (the first one) Thanks for adding the tag, I was MIA while you guys were commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The things  she had told him couldn't be got out of her by just anyone**.

It is just a matter of  usage. Both  are correct.

The Americans might use gotten and the British might use  got. But  gotten  is slowly  creeping into  the  British  Usage too.

Here is a link to  show the difference.

https://jakubmarian.com/got-vs-gotten-in-english/

Here is another link to make things clear.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gotten

Comment: +1 for a good and correct answer.  But, links often break.  It's best to quote directly the portion of the linked material you wish to highlight in addition to that link.

Comment: @JVL I appreciate the helpful links. I’m American, but since this is a sentence from a novel I’m writing and it seems that whether or not this is frowned at all depends on who’s reading it, I think I’ll keep it as is. My concern was whether or not I’d made a blatant mistake. Oddly enough, as I said, I liked the sentence with ‘got’ better, but something was tickling at the back of my brain that said it might make others scratch their heads.